# PushListener in the Background of Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to create a PushListener that will take an action once a specific push is recieved.

For example, when the server sends a push like "UPDATE TIMER 5", then the iOS app will update the TIMER to 5 seconds.

I haven't been able to find any examples of code that do this, but I have read blogs where people say they have done this.

Any hints of how to do this or where to look for some example code?

Comment: why dont you just send a notification? via NotificationCenter

Answer (score 0):

Well, solution is notifications. For example, you have class:

```
class NotificationExampleClass {
    var stringUpdatedByNotification: String = ""
}
```

So, the basic idea of notification is to update some value (in our case `stringUpdatedByNotification`) immediately when we want (when we post notification).

Before we post notification, we need to add `addObserver`/`removeObserver` and function that receive notification:

```
class NotificationExampleClass {
    var stringUpdatedByNotification: String = ""

    init() {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self,
          selector: "updateNotificationString:", // method called when notification have been received
          name: "notificationId", 
          object: nil)
    }

    deinit {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, 
          name: "notificationId", 
          object: nil)
    }

    func updateNotificationString(notification: NSNotification) {
        let userInfo = notification.userInfo as! [String: String] // or unwrap to your custom key value pair type
        stringUpdatedByNotification = userInfo["myKey"]!
    }
}
```

And now we just need to set our `userInfo` dictionary and post notification:

```
func postNotification() {
    let userInfo = ["myKey" : "notificationPostValue"]
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("notificationId", object: userInfo)
}
```

and our `stringUpdatedByNotification` equals string `"notificationPostValue"`.

Feel free to update code to your own situations. Good luck.

**Update:**

Of course, pass dictionary as `[String: String]` to `userInfo` is more obj-c way to do this things. In Swift (and in your particularly case) you can pass to `userInfo` all that confirm to `[NSObject : AnyObject]?`, because `userInfo` declared as
`var userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]? { get }`. So, when you create something like control-flow notification, i suggest you to create `enum` for it:

```
enum  TimerControl: AnyObject {
    case UpdateToFiveSeconds, UpdateToTenSeconds
}
```

And now pass to `userInfo` this `["myKey": .UpdateToFiveSeconds]`.
In this case you can get `TimeControl` object via `notification.userInfo["key"]`, not string and avoid any mistake in `String` value.